# Confused about a struct's location in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, memory-address

I'm exploring pointers and am currently messing with struct pointers in particular.  Currently, I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct point{
double x;
double y;
};

int main(){
    char *pc;
    int *pi;
    struct point *pp;

    //char pointer
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pc);
    pc++;
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pc);

    //int pointer
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pi);
    pi += 2;
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pi);

    //struct pointer
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pp);
    pp -= 3;
    printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pp);
}
```

The output of this code is this:

```
0x104978036

0x104978037

0x7fff5ec4bbc8

0x7fff5ec4bbd0

0x0

0xffffffffffffffd0
```

I understand the first 4 outputs, with `char` and `int` pointer arithmetic, however I'm confused why it returns `0x0` for the `struct` pointer's memory address?  Also, if I wanted the address of say, `double y` in memory, how would I print that?

Comment: "I understand...". No you don't. There's nothing to "understand" here. The code's behavior is completely meaningless, since none of the variables are initialized.

Comment: What I mean is I understand the jump from 36 to 37, and from bbc8 to bbd0  due to the size of a char and int, I'm still learning C and didn't realize this was undefined behavior, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code invokes *Undefined Behavior*, since all your pointers are used **uninitialized**!

Compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall` for GCC) and will get:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:15:5: warning: 'pc' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pc);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c:20:5: warning: 'pi' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pi);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c:25:5: warning: 'pp' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("%p\n\n", (void*)pp);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

Initialize your pointers like this, for example:

```
char c = 'a';
char *pc = &c;
int i = 5;
int *pi = &i;
struct point p;
struct point *pp = &p;
```

and could get:

```
0x7ffe629c90d7 // address of the charatcer

0x7ffe629c90d8 // sizeof(char) is 1

0x7ffe629c90d0 // address of the integer

0x7ffe629c90d8 // sizeof(int) is 8 in this system

0x7ffe629c90c0 // address of the struct

0x7ffe629c9090 // sizeof(struct point) is 16 in this system
// 0x7ffe629c90c0 - 0x7ffe629c9090 = 0x30 -> Decimal: 48 = 3 * 16
```

Comment: Doing pointer math on a `NULL` pointer (or on any pointer if you go out of bounds, even without dereferencing) is also UB.

Comment: Is there a reason the initialized primitive types have junk values while the struct is set to zero?

Comment: @Carl I don't see the struct set to zero.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a  pointer you have to allocate memory to it or set it to null if you won't use it.

```
pc = malloc(sizeof(*pc));
pi = malloc(sizeof(*pi));
pp = malloc(sizeof(*pp));
```

Don't forget to verify the return value of malloc !!!! (didn't did it on purpose)

You should compile with `-W -Wall -Wextra -g` and then run the binary with `valgrind`.

Furthermore, you don't need to cast to void * as it is already a pointer

Here is the result :

```
0xf88010

0xf88011

0xf88030

0xf88038

0xf88050

0xf88020
```